# CoffeeScript List Comprehensions / Array Comprehensions

Tags: coffeescript

CoffeeScript list comprehensions are slightly different from Pythons... which of these is the way that people like to return list comprehensions?

```
return elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3] # returns 3+1
return [elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3]].pop() # returns [2,3,4]
return (elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3]) # returns [2,3,4]
```

In Python, I would just write:

```
return [elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3]]
```

And it returns the list correctly, instead of a list of lists, as this would do in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which of these is the way that people like to return list comprehensions?

```
return elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3] # returns 3+1
return [elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3]].pop() # returns [2,3,4]
return (elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3]) # returns [2,3,4]
```

Well, of the three options, certainly #3. But the best stylistic choice is actually this:

```
elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3] # returns [2,3,4]
```

As the last line of a function, any expression `expr` is equivalent to `return (expr)`. The `return` keyword is very rarely necessary.

Comment: Note you can't assign using this, i.e.  `someVar = elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3]`  gets a value of 4.  Annoyingly, though understandably, you still have to put the list comprehension in parenthesis like: `someVar = (elem+1 for elem in [1,2,3])`

Answer (score 2):

I've never used CoffeeScript, but if my options were getting the wrong result, doing a silly `[...].pop()` kludge or just using a set of parenthesis, I'd go for the parenthesis.

Comment: I have used CoffeeScript, and this is indeed essentially correct. :) But see my answer for further elaboration.